# Shopware 6: Not compiling my main.js in my custom plugin

Tags: javascript, build, compilation, shopware6

I added custom javascript in my custom plugin theme. I did exactly what is descriped here:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript

My main.js is in:

`custom/plugins/myplugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js`

I compile my javascript with the command:

`./bin/build-storefront.sh`

Now I would expect my javascript (in compiled form of course) here:

`plublic/theme/mythemehash/js/all.js`

But it is not there! The all.js is existing but my javascript is not in there. The creation date of the all.js file is equal to when I compiled my command, so the compiling it self runs, but my main.js is not taken into account.

What can I do?

*Shopware 6.4.20.1*

*.env/ APP_ENV=dev*

Answer (score 1):

After you run the build script, the compiled assets of your plugin should be located at `MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/dist/storefront/js`. If it's there your assets have been successfully compiled. Make sure your plugin is active and installed when you run the script, otherwise your plugin's assets will be ignored. To do so from the CLI you can run these two commands in order:

```
bin/console plugin:refresh
bin/console plugin:install MyPlugin --activate
```

In theory you shouldn't have to do anything else But you could still try to manually install the assets and compile the theme. To do so run these two commands from within the shopware root directory, one after the other:

```
bin/console assets:install
bin/console theme:compile
```

Comment: Yes I got a compiled file in dist/storefront/js/myplugin.js. But still the script is not used in the frontend. I could write the path in theme.json but I do not know if this is the right way. In theory I shouldn't have to do anything ... And the developer documentation also says nothing about to put the path in theme.json.

Comment: @ChristianMichael yeah you need to put the script path in the theme.json.      "script": [
       "@Storefront",
       "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/my-backend-plugin.js"
     ]